# How to sign a message using Yubikey

Tags: digital-signature, yubico

I'm interested in using a yubikey to sign a message. Im aware that openPGP can be used to sign a message using a yubikey but the signature includes some metadata as described here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-openpgp-rfc4880bis-06#section-5.2.4

For my use case, I'd like to just sign a message or a hash of a message and thats it(no extra metadata).
Is there something like a C library interface to use for signing a message using a yubikey?

Comment: Which model of YubiKey? Which signature algorithm? Which hashing algorithm?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen preferably the 5Ci model. Im particularly interested in secp256k1 which seems like it's supported in their latest firmware update. I'm not fussed about hashing algo as I can hash the message outside of the yubikey. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSC offers an pkcs11 implementation to interface the Yubikey as a PKI device 
https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki